# Setting Canvas Style to a Changing Variable

Tags: javascript, canvas

Why does this work,

```
var color = Math.sin( time ) * 128;
color = 128;
context.fillStyle = "rgb(" + color + ", " + color + ", " + color + ")";
```

But this does not?

```
var color = Math.sin( time ) * 128;
color += 128;
context.fillStyle = "rgb(" + color + ", " + color + ", " + color + ")";
```

For some reason, the variable stops working once it becomes dynamic.

Comment: have you inspected the value of `color` in a console? What is it?

Comment: Your tip pointed me in the right direction; thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. I'm sending a floating value where canvas is looking for an integer.

It should be Math.floor(Math.sin( time ) * 128);